# How should I sandbox a thread and do simple IO?

Tags: linux

I have code written by a third party. It seems fine but I suspect there are bugs and may be exploitable. Is there some way I can isolate this from the rest of my code?

The two main ways I can think of doing this is

1. Create a few pipes then call clone with `CLONE_FILES|CLONE_THREAD` and that'll share nothing but pipes (and files won't be shared because of O_CLOEXEC? I'm not sure if O_CLOEXEC applies to clones/threads). Then do all the IO with read/write
2. Share nothing except a few MBs of memory. The thread would need to be able to call the syscall `futex` so the main thread can wake it up/third party code can sleep and not need to spinlock. I already have threading code that does this

The issue I have is I'm not sure how if I'm really sandboxing the thread (can it corrupt my memory? files? Can I prevent it from touching the filesystem?). I'm not familiar with newns, cgroup etc I'm not sure what I should be doing

Using x86-64 assembly is fine. My main code is in C++ with a few in C

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The clone() parameters only prevent the thread from touching your process' memory directly (almost making it a new *process* rather than a thread), but they don't prevent the thread from making external library calls, system calls, opening *new* file handles, etc. It's certainly a *start*, but won't save you if the thread is tricked into calling open(".ssh/id_rsa") or something.

To actually limit what a child process or thread can do to the system, you'll need [seccomp](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/seccomp.2.html). Figure out the minimum set of system calls that your module can live with, use seccomp to allow only those and block the rest. (While the default action on violation is "kill the process", it's possible to make blocked calls return a fake error code as well.) You can use [libseccomp](https://readthedocs.org/projects/libseccomp/) to build a profile instead of writing the BPF bytecode by hand.

Some sandboxing techniques are only available to root, e.g. putting the process in its own namespaces using `CLONE_NEW*` (those are sometimes achieved using setuid wrappers, like Chrome and Flatpak's bwrap do). Mount namespaces, like chroots, are effective for preventing the process from opening random files on the system – but you have to be root to set them up.

If you're writing a service, and could refactor it to have the third-party code in a fully separate daemon (that the main service talks to via IPC), then those techniques (as well as syscall filtering) could be applied by the service manager such as systemd. That is, you'd have the main "foo.service" which is privileged, plus the additional "foo-worker.service" which is highly restricted using the options that systemd exposes – including chroots, namespaces, and seccomp.

Comment: Good to know. Seccomp looks very complicated. The example in the man page is currently over my head (I never seen BPF before). But I'll read the page start to end and anything else it suggest and hopefully I'll understand by the end of it

Comment: Right, it's meant to be used through libseccomp (which lets you just specify the syscalls you want, smooths out differences between architectures having slightly different syscalls, etc) rather than directly.